# How can I rotate a stepper motor northwards?

Tags: motor

I am working on a project where I need to rotate a stepper motor North, South, East and West. To implement this, it seems like you just need to know where one direction is, say North. Given that, you can easily workout the other directions.

But how can I know where north is? I was thinking of making a switch that gets closed when the motor is in the North position. But when I tried this, the wires got really taught from being spun so much. This approach won't work.

Another thing I tried is to start at North, and then keep track of every movement. This should work, but it's brittle.

Surely there is a good way to do this?

Comment: Use a limit switch and an actuator attached to the stepper spindle?